# Ajax Tree With jqTree

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using jqTree to convert json data to an easily viewable tree. I want to load the tree nodes one level at a time, so page loading will be faster and the nodes will be accessed only when needed. However, when I send the nodes at, say, depth 0, to jqTree, the expand icon doesn't appear.

How can I implement this tree without sending the whole batch of data at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *dev* branch of jqtree contains a new feature for loading a subtree. The function **loadData** now accepts a **parent_node** parameter.

`$tree.tree('loadData', data, parent_node);`

Also see https://github.com/mbraak/jqTree/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with jqTree unless you make some changes to the coffee/javascript. Look at my fork on github:

https://github.com/dougnorton/jqTree

Take a look at the demo2.html page.

Comment: Please do not post just a link. It could be come dead. Please post something that could be of relevance to future users.